# Cómo imprimir un archivo JSON en HTML - Angular

Tags: html, angular, json

lo que busco hacer es poder imprimir mi archivo .JSON en el html, utilizando un span o algo que me pueda mostrar la información que se encuentra dentro.

Más abajo puse un ejemplo, en donde muestro que los trabajadores se muestran en consola, pero necesito poder mostrarlos en el HTML. He intentado varias formas, cambiando el formato del JSON y todo, pero no encuentro cuál puede ser la falla, o cómo puedo recorrer el json desde HTML.

Quiero imprimir esto, pero en HTML (Este es un ejemplo console.log())

```
{empleado-1: 0, empleado-2: 1, empleado-3: 2, empleado-4: 2, empleado-5: 2}
empleado-1: 0
empleado-2: 1
empleado-3: 2
empleado-4: 2
empleado-5: 2
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Este es mi JSON el cuál quiero imprimirlo en HTML.

```
{
    "planificacion": [
      {
        "empleado-1": 2,
        "empleado-2": 1,
        "empleado-3": 2,
        "empleado-4": 2,
        "empleado-5": 0
      },
      {
        "empleado-1": 1,
        "empleado-2": 2,
        "empleado-3": 2,
        "empleado-4": 0,
        "empleado-5": 2
      },
      {
        "empleado-1": 0,
        "empleado-2": 1,
        "empleado-3": 2,
        "empleado-4": 2,
        "empleado-5": 2
      }
    ]
  }
```

Aquí debajo tengo el código HTML con un *ngFor para imprimir la propiedad, pero no me funciona en este caso.

```html
<div class="schedule-item" *ngFor="let schedule of scheduleWorkers | async">
  <span> {{ schedule.planificacion }} </span>
</div>
```

Mi archivo Servicio.

```
   const response = await fetch('assets/schedule.json');
   const json = await response.json()

   console.log(json.planificacion)
   
   json.planificacion.forEach((elemento: any) => {
     console.log(elemento)
   }) 
 }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en ESPAÑOL, las preguntas deben ir en el idioma oficial, que es español. Te sugiero editar tu pregunta y traducirla o preguntar el stackoverflow en ingles.

Comment: This is the spanish forum. Ask here https://stackoverflow.com/ ;)

Comment: Ya lo actualicé, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tengo poca experiencia en angular pero teóricamente esto podría funcionar:

```html
<div class="schedule-item" *ngFor="let object of json.planificacion; let i = index">
  <div> 
    Index:  {{ i }}
    <div *ngFor="let itemName in object">
      <p> {{ itemName + ": " + object[itemName] }} </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comenta si dió resultado o no.

Comment: Hola!, al final el problema era que tenía definido el archivo JSON de otra manera, pero igual muchas gracias!

Comment: Estamos aquí para ayudar, me alegra que hayas encontrado el problema.